# htaccess how to redirect all pages, but not the root directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i need a help witch an htaccess 301 redirect.

I have a site www.site.com but i need to change all pages to www.newsite.com but i want not move www.site.com (for a pages information)

EXAMPLE:

```
www.site.com (not move) index of to put then a template or message

www.site.com/2012/08/page.html move to www.newsite.com/2012/08/page.html
www.site.com/tag/keyword/ move to www.newsite.com/tag/keyword/
www.site.com/category/general/ move to www.newite.com/category/general/
```

how i can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could try using mod_alias' `RedirectMatch` to force something in the URI for the redirect. In the htaccess file in site.com's document root, add:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1
```

This will make it so anything after `http://www.site.com/` will get redirected, but just `http://www.site.com/` will not. However, `http://www.site.com/index.html` *will* get redirected. If that's an issue, you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
# and whatever else you don't want redirected
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Using this assets gets redirected too. It's right, but probably not what the op wanted.

Answer (score 2):

On `www.site.com` host Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @anubhava: Always my savior on this site. Can't thank you enough.