# htaccess how to redirect just the root not other pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem witch htaccess i need to redirect just the root site (main page) but not the traffic goin to the other pages.

Example:

Main domain: `www.misite.com` (redirect to another.com)

Request from http: `www.misite.com/?other-page` (not redirect)

Request from http: `www.misite.com/?another-page` (not redirect)

I just move all the traffic from `www.misite.com` / `misite.com` to other place, but not the other pages, internal, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess how to redirect all pages, but not the root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999047/htaccess-how-to-redirect-all-pages-but-not-the-root-directory)

Answer (score 3):

Using mod_alias, in either the htaccess or vhost config for the misite.com site.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://another.com/?
```