# 301 Redirect All Internal URL - but NOT the homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like my landing page to stay the same.  So loading `www.sample.com/` will not redirect anything.  However, anything after that, such as `www.sample.com/page-link/`  will redirect to the new site `www.newsite.com/page-link/`.

I tried this

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) http://www.newsite.com/
```

But it redirects the homepage.  Again, the homepage (root url) of www.sample.com should load as it normally does.  But any query added in the form of

`/permalink-here/` should be redirected. Is this something that is simple to do?

EDIT : I did search StackOverflow and the suggested duplicate does not work.  It redirects the homepage (root url) which is not what I want.  This may be relevant, my URLs are already formatted to auto add the trailing slash - even on the root.

So, for this to function I need the redirect to only be called if someone is added after the trailing slash.

Example:

`www.sample.com/` - **DO NOT REDIRECT**

`www.sample.com/permalink-here/` - **REDIRECT**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999047/htaccess-how-to-redirect-all-pages-but-not-the-root-directory

Comment: @emmanuel - I tried both of those answers and neither works.  I assume that is why neither have upvotes.

Comment: @Jared and what other rules do you have in your `.htaccess` currently?

Comment: Prix - Only the standard wordpress stuff.  You can see it listed here [wordpress.codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) under Basic WP

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Or

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.+)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1
```